# WebStorm cannot go to declaration for node js module's methods?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using some modules and with every modules I have same problem using WebStorm as my IDE. For example:

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
yargs.parse()
```

Whenever I try to go to declaration of `parse()`, it fails, `Cannot find declaration to go to` error. Like this:

[image]

My file structure looks likes this:

[image]

And coding assistance is enabled:

[image: js]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yargs` properties are generated dynamically and thus can't be resolved during static code analysis.

Installing typings (using `npm install @types/yargs`, or via the intention available on `Alt+Enter` - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files) should help

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Is it mandatory for developers to provide @type for every library they develop and deploy on npm?